# Whois wildcard query

Tags: domain-name, whois

In a dicussion with an organization owning the "foo" trademark I'd like to look for all domains containing foo in their name or at least domains starting with "foo". How could I do such a whois search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best search engine I know of for this kind of search is the one provided by [N@me Droppers](http://www.namedroppers.com/). Type your trademark in the search bar and use the pull down to select "Only Registered Domains".

To test it, I put in "superuser" (in .com only) and it found superuser.com, androidsuperuser.com, asciisuperuser.com, asksuperuser,com, beasuperuser.com, superuserfilter.com, and so on.

Comment: That doesnt work any more

Answer (score 1):

Old question but still relevant. So 2 main ways:

1. From a unix command line to query the Verisign com/net records:

   whois keyword*
   or
   whois -h whois.internic.net keyword*

Depending on the default settings of your whois program (check with 'man whois').

Note the (optional) wildcard. This will return max 50 records , priority: -,0-9,a-z

2. From a web interface to the Internic WHOIS:

[Wildcard Whois web app](https://www.cheapnames.com/wildcard-whois)

Verisign wildcard lookups are also provided at: 
whois.crsnic.net
whois.verisign-grs.net (com.whois-servers.net)

This covers .com / .net / .edu  only. I do not know of similar tools for any other TLDs.

Note: normal WHOIS servers do not support wildcards.

Comment: I get an invalid query If i use a wildcard

Comment: From a command line? Or the web version above? Asterisk (*) can only be at the end, no spaces.

Comment: on a command line with no spaces

Comment: Actually quotes are also necessary to prevent local file matches:whois -h whois.internic.net "keyword*"

Comment: Also whois runs on port 43 which may be blocked by some providers/facilites so the web version will be needed, even for a standard whois query but there are many sites who offer that eg. https://who.is

Comment: none of these work today :-( . I ended up writing a script to find the digits of the XXXsomeword.com domain: `for i in {100..999}; do; nslookup ${i}actualword.com >/dev/null && echo "actualword$i.com"; done`

Comment: You have your digits before and after the keyword in that code but just to confirm .. the WHOIS wildcard query only works for the wildcard at the end.