# WHOIS query for specific TLD and Registrar

Tags: whois

Is there any way to query the public WHOIS like this:

Give me all registered domain names for this extension AND by this registrar:

```
whois ".ext" AND whois.registrar.ext
```

Of course I'm aiming at extension/registrar combination that will return no more then 20 results (Thanks to ICANN stats data).

[Whois wildcard query](https://superuser.com/questions/502450/whois-wildcard-query)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is not a single WHOIS database but rather many different WHOIS servers. Each WHOIS server usually provides data for one or more specific TLDs. Here's a rather [comprehensive list](https://www.nirsoft.net/whois_servers_list.html) of TLDs and the WHOIS server that handles each.

I'm not aware of a tool that can perform a WHOIS lookup and specify the Registrar as a criterion. You will likely need to create your own script to do that. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26956563/2227908) on StackOverflow may help you with that.

Be mindful that WHOIS servers use rate-limiting so you'll only be able to perform a relatively small number of lookups before you're throttled or blocked altogether.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and posting an answer. 
I found something that is very close to what I want here: 
http://reversewhois.domaintools.com/ 
(Reverse Whois) 
Unfortunately price is too high for me.